# Let $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n$ be sequences of real number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n$ be sequences of real number. Suppose $a_0=b_{2020}$ and $b_0=a_{2020}$ and that $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{2}+a_{n-1}$ and $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{1010}-b_{n-1}$ for $n=1,2,\dots,2020$. Find $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2020}(a_kb_{k-1}-a_{k-1}b_k)$.

My attempt:

Let $$S_{2020}=\sum_{k=1}^{2020}(a_kb_{k-1}-a_{k-1}b_k)$$
then
\begin{align*}
S_{2020}&=\sum_{k=1}^{2020}\left(\frac{a_{k-1}\sqrt{2k-3}}{1010}-\frac{b_{k-2}{\sqrt{2k-1}}}{2}-\frac{a_{k-2}\sqrt{2k-1}}{1010}-\frac{b_{k-1}{\sqrt{2k-3}}}{2}\right)-S_{2019}+(a_1b_0-a_0b_1)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two relations can be rearranged and multiplied to give $$(a_k-a_{k-1})(b_k+b_{k-1})=\frac{2k-1}{2020}$$

$$(a_kb_k-a_{k-1}b_{k-1}) + (a_kb_{k-1}-a_{k-1}b_k)=\frac{2k-1}{2020}$$

Now summing over,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2020} (a_kb_k-a_{k-1}b_{k-1}) + \sum_{k=1}^{2020} (a_kb_{k-1}-a_{k-1}b_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{2020} \frac{2k-1}{2020}$$

The first sum telescopes. The second term is our desired sum, $S$. RHS is a multiple of sum of first $2020$ odd numbers, which is simply $2020^2$.

$$(a_{2020}b_{2020}-a_0b_0) + S =2020$$

Since $a_{2020}=b_0$ and $b_{2020}=a_0$, $$\boxed{S=2020}$$